# How to increase my concentration for Japa?

Tags: rama, puja, kali, japa, nama-japa

Recently, I'm not getting interest to do japa. While I somehow doing the japa internally (Rama nama), I used to get Maa Kalika sometimes in meditation too. Now, I'm not getting interest to do any japa and puja if anything I'm getting sexual urges. And I'm falling into the trap everyday. Now is there a way to increase my concentration towards my japa. I'm also feeling a little disconnected too. And I'm some problems personally I think they are affecting my spiritual path also. If anybody has any suggestions for me let me know.